# Backbone error, Object [object global] has no method ...

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

In the code below the navigator throws me an error,i´m using backbone.js with require.js to load a books from a view, this is my code:

BookListView.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'collections/bookCollection',
    'views/bookView'
], function ($, _, Backbone, bookCollection, bookView) {

    var books = [{ ... }];

    var BookListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#books'),

        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'renderBook');
            this.collection = new bookCollection(books);
            this.render();
        },

        render: function () {
            _.each(this.collection.models, function (item) {
                this.renderBook(item);
            });
        },

        renderBook: function (item) {
            var BookView = new bookView({
                model: item
            });
            this.$el.append(BookView.render().el);
        }
    });

    return BookListView;

});
```

And the console returns me the error: **Object [object global] has no method 'renderBook'**

Could you help me please?

Comment: As an aside, `this.collection.each(...)` would be better than `_.each(this.collection.models, ...)`, collections have [various Underscore methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add explicity the context to the each call:

```
_.each(this.collection.models, function (item) {
    this.renderBook(item);
}, this);
```